# time.process_time() giving constant value

Tags: python, python-3.x, time

I'm trying to measure CPU time on my script with `time.process_time()`, but it is always returning the same value. Here's my code:

```py
import time

pt0 = time.process_time()
secuencia = [int(num) for num in '2,9,5,14,4,13,1,7,6,12,11,3,8,10'.split(',')]

pt1 = time.process_time()

n = 0
acumulado = 0
for num in secuencia:
    if num > n:
        n = num
    acumulado += num

num_perdido = int(n*(n+1)/2 - acumulado)

if num_perdido == 0:
    n += 1
    num_perdido = n

pt2 = time.process_time()

print('pt0 =', pt0)
print('pt1 =', pt1)
print('pt2 =', pt2)
```

The file `secuencia.txt` contains the following:

```
2,9,5,14,4,13,1,7,6,12,11,3,8,10
```

And the output is:

```
pt0 = 0.0625
pt1 = 0.0625
pt2 = 0.0625
```

Is it because of how the function works, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data (e.g. a list of values) instead of reading from a file we do not have?

Comment: What is the output of ``print(time.process_time())``? It should return a float value, but your output implies integers.

Comment: I edited and added the data on `secuencia.txt`, and the output  is corrected now, I copied the output from the wrong run

Comment: Note that your program is not doing very much. On my machine, the differences are merely ``0.00009`` (``pt1-pt0``) and ``0.00018`` (``pt2-pt1``). If your machine is faster, it might be below the clock resolution. Do some significant computation when doing performance measurement.

Comment: you could use a [time.perf_counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter_ns) instead and see if that works for you.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably because the computation is pretty simple.`time.process_time()` gives a constant value, and `time.perf_counter()`gives a little difference. The difference is that the first uses the CPU counter for the current process, and the second uses the global counter, right?

Answer (score 1):

please check if there is any data in `secuencia.txt.`
I did checked it with some data, it looks fine.

```
pt0 = 0.045034
pt1 = 0.045148
pt2 = 0.045154
```

Comment: I just edited the question and added the data on `secuencia.txt`. Just checked and it wasn't empty.

Comment: Your code is perfectly fine.
there is this issue already logged https://bugs.python.org/issue37859
are you using windows.

Comment: try to use time.perf_counter()
 https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/time-perf_counter-function-in-python/#:~:text=perf_counter()%20function%20always%20returns,sleep%20and%20is%20system%2Dwide.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows... So it seems that it may be caused due to this:
`perf_counter and process_time have very different properties. process_time is stopped when the process sleeps, for example.`